# lua load path for shared objects

Tags: lua

I'm using lua 5.3beta under Kubuntu 12.04. I wrapped a c-extension using swig  used and gcc4.9 for compiling and linking. If I place my mylib.so in the same directory my lua script is in:

```
require "mylib"
```

works fine. But if mylib.so is not within the same directory I get the error message

```
module 'mylib' not found
```

I added the path to mylib to LD_LIBRARY_PATH and inserted

```
package.path  = package.path .. ';' .. path2mylib .. '/?
```

in my script. With

```
package.path  = package.path .. ';' .. path2mylib .. '/?.so
```

the error message is:

```
mylib.so:1: unexpected symbol near '<\127>
```

I guess lua tries to load mylib.so assuming it is a lua-script.
It seems that lua looks for shared objects only within certain standard paths including ./ and all paths added to package.path are treated as paths to lua-files.

Is there any way to make lua load my c-extension without placing it into one of the standard library paths?

Answer (score 4):

The path variable that tells Lua where to find libraries written in C is `package.cpath`.

`package.path` is for libraries written in Lua.